# How can I preload a screen in a Stack Navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I have a Stack Navigator where screen A pushes to screen B.

I would like to preload screen B so there is no lag when pushing from screen A. How can I do that?

I've seen there is a [`lazy: false`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#lazy) option for bottom tab navigators, is there something similar for Stack Navigators?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this in a Stack Navigator from what I understood by the [Github Issue #6010](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6010).

> In drawer/tabs, there are a fixed number of all screens, so all of
> them can be rendered and you just navigate to an existing screen. The
> order in which the screens are rendered is also fixed.
>
> It doesn't make sense for stack. There's no limit to how many screens
> that can be rendered and there's no guarantee about order of screens
> or what is the next screen. There can also be multiple instances of
> the same screen.
>
> The navigation state for stack is populated you push a new screen as
> opposed to drawer it tabs where there state already includes all
> screens.

I found the above after I read the Github Issue "[How to mount all screens on App load](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7140)".

Comment: Correcting typos: Perhaps there is a way to fork the stack navigator? Perhaps you know how? Thanks for your answer, insightful link!